# Golang. MongoDB bulkWrite() to update slice of documents

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a slice of objects I want to save to Mongo collection. Let's say

```
type (
    User struct {
        AccountId       string
        Name            string
        FamilyName      string
        EmailAddress    string
    }
)

func persistUsers(ctx context.Context, db *mongo.Collection, users []User) {

}
```

Some users are already saved, some - aren't. I want to upsert the slice. Hence I have two question:

1. How can I user `mongo.Collection.BulkWrite()`? I can't find obvious explanation how to put slice of objects into it.
2. How do mongo decides what is new, what is old and has to be updated? According to `_id`?

Comment: Not really that clear what you are asking here. Perhaps show a *small* sample of documents you have, a *small* sample of input and the expected result you want to achieve. I suspect you're just talking about [upserts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option), but the current content of the question ( which is really little more than a struct and no operational code ) really does not adequately demonstrate what you are expecting. Please revise the question with a more concise example, as described

Comment: which mogo db package you are using?  if its mgo you can use collectionname.Bulk() only for bulk update

Comment: no, I use `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can I use mongo.Collection.BulkWrite()?

This example code is based on [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) v1.1.2. First you need to import the following:

```
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
```

And below is the example code for [Collection.BulkWrite](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.BulkWrite) and utilises your `User` struct example:

```
collection := client.Database("databaseName").Collection("collectionName")

var operations []mongo.WriteModel

// Example using User struct
userA := User{AccountId:"1", Name:"John", FamilyName:"Smith", EmailAddress:"john@example.org"}

operationA := mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
operationA.SetFilter(bson.M{"AccountId": userA.AccountId}) 
operationA.SetUpdate(bson.M{"Name":userA.Name, 
                            "FamilyName":userA.FamilyName, 
                            "EmailAddress":userA.EmailAddress})
// Set Upsert flag option to turn the update operation to upsert
operationA.SetUpsert(true) 
operations = append(operations, operationA)

// Example using bson.M{}
operationB := mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
operationB.SetFilter(bson.M{"AccountId":2}) 
operationB.SetUpdate(bson.M{"Name":"Jane", 
                              "FamilyName":"Smith", 
                              "EmailAddress":"jane@example.org"})
operationB.SetUpsert(true) 
operations = append(operations, operationB)

// Specify an option to turn the bulk insertion in order of operation
bulkOption := options.BulkWriteOptions{}
bulkOption.SetOrdered(true)

result, err := collection.BulkWrite(context.TODO(), operations, &bulkOption)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

For more information please see:

- MongoDB Go driver [options.BulkWriteOptions](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#BulkWriteOptions)
- MongoDB Go driver [options.UpdateOptions](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#UpdateOptions)
- MongoDB [db.collection.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

> How do mongo decides what is new, what is old and has to be updated?

If there is no document matches the query criteria (the filter), then `update()` inserts a single document. If there are documents that match the query criteria it becomes an update. See also [Upsert Behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) for more information.

If your update query criteria contains `_id` with [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation), please see [Upsert With Dotted `_id` Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id).

Comment: Can I upsert an array of users in one operation? To perform all the job on mongo side?

Comment: Depends on the filter, typically on upsert operation you would want to specify a specific filter for a document. You can perform multiple inserts in one operation using `insertMany()`.

Comment: So with this approach if there are 1000 entries, there would be 1000 operations, will that cause delay

Comment: @UtsavGupta depends on your MongoDB configuration and server capacity.

Comment: @WanBachtiar Why do I get this `update document must contain key beginning with '$`

Comment: @WanBachtiar go it 

```operationB.SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": data})```

Answer (score 0):

Anybody looking for a solution to update particular key:value of a collection of documents,

This will also create a new document if that field doesn't exist.

```
func UpdateData(data []User) {
    upsert := true
    after := options.After

    collection := client.Database("dbname").Collection("colname")

    for _, user := range data {
        
        // Create the search filter
        filter := bson.M{"name": user.Name}
        
        // Create the update 
        update := bson.M{
            "$set": bson.M{"AccountId": user.AccountID}, // New Account ID
        }
        
        // Create an instance of an options and set the desired options.
        opt := options.FindOneAndUpdateOptions{
            ReturnDocument: &after,
            Upsert:         &upsert,
        }
        
        // Find one result and update it
        result := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(context.Background(), filter, update, &opt)
        
        if result.Err() != nil {
            log.Printf("user account id update failed: %v\n", result.Err())
        }
    }
}
```

Argument **data []User** assumes you have a slice of structures with new values to be updated in the database.